# How to resolve FirebaseMLException com.google.firebase.ml.common.FirebaseMLException?

Tags: android, ocr, firebase-mlkit

FirebaseMLException com.google.firebase.ml.common.FirebaseMLException: Waiting for the text recognition model to be downloaded. Please wait.

I am developing one android app in that i am using ML Kit for OCR text recognization but in some devices getting above exception so is there any way to detect OCR on device model get downloaded or not into device. Currently i am following this document https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text for on device text recognization functionality integration.

Below meta-data added into androidmanifext.xml file

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.ml.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="ocr,barcode" />

private FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer textRecognizer = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getOnDeviceTextRecognizer();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am facing the same issue for face detection for samsung devices. Did you get any solution?